# Error when reading from byte stream:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Tags: c#, memorystream

I've opened a byte stream on a file that's about 3.5 meg. The contents are Int32's in arrays, each arrays is separated by a unique 64-bit magic number and then some Int32s with the dimensions, followed by the data.

I'm about half way through the file, array 548 of 1001, when I get this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: MemoryStream length must be non-negative and less than 2^31 - 1 - origin.
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
S.Position = ByteStart + 8
```

`S` is the stream. `ByteStart` is 873552. The addition produces the correct value, 873560. The file is much longer than this. Can anyone offer a suggestion as to why I might be getting this error?

Comment: You have described only part of the problem, and you have described what you think is going on.  What is probably going on is something very different from what you think is going on.  So, please post an [mcve] (with emphasis on the "Minimal" part.)

Comment: This error means you are setting Position to the value greater than int.MaxValue (2147483647).

Comment: @evk, no that is not what the error message is saying ;-)  (length must be `non-negative` and less than `2^31 - 1 - origin`)

Comment: @elgonzo you can try it yourself (or look at source code of `MemoryStream.Position`). As for your comment: you can set Position to value larger than stream length and it will not cause any exception.

Comment: @Evk, oh, you are right. I retract my former statements. Not only can you set the position beyond the stream end, but setting a negative stream position produces a different error message.

Comment: @elgonzo well this error message is completely misleading. Not related to negatives and not related to `2^31 - 1 - origin` (instead just compares with int.MaxValue ignoring origin).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this appears to have turned out to be a threading issue. I noticed that when I hovered the mouse over the variables I got one set of values, and a different set in the Watch window and neither of these appeared to be the actual value. For whatever reason, at some point ByteStart became a super-large value, although this didn't seem to be happening if I just traced though the code step-by-step, it only happened if it was just running on its own. Weird!